# I need arm64-android folder

Tags: vcpkg

~/vcpkg/installed/arm64-android
When I install vcpkg in  linux (Ubuntu 20.04) then some file missing from this folder. So please share me this

When I install vcpkg in  linux (Ubuntu 20.04) then some file missing from this folder. So please share me this